# Showing "mydomain.com" if I enter "mydomain.com/index.htm"

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, directoryindex

Like most servers, if I enter: www.mydomain.com, my server shows www.mydomain.com/index.htm and my Browser continues to show www.mydomain.com

But if I enter into my Browser www.mydomain.com/index.htm, can I tweak htaccess to show www.mydomain.com in my Browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.htm [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks for that, shall look forward to trying it out.